# VSCode debugger conditional breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently debugging a python project, and I would like to add conditional breakpoints similar to the [conditional breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce(v=vs.100).aspx) in Visual Studio. Is this feature supported and if so, how do I create one?

Comment: With VSCode 1.55 (March 2021), you now can break on variables when there are accessed/read. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149091/6309).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Right click on an existing breakpoint and select "Edit Breakpoint…", or right click on the breakpoint margin and select "Add Conditional Breakpoint…".

See the [VS Code Debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_conditional-breakpoints) for details.

Comment: The example given on the documentation page is for a hit count. Can you give an example of a conditional breakpoint expression? When I add breakpoints, they're always getting hit, even if I enter `0` (which should always evaluate to false) as the expression.

Comment: You have to press "enter" to confirm your expression.

Comment: @mKay Thanks, this is an important detail, to me quite unintuitive

Comment: Should we write expression in python, my vs code does not detect python in 'Conditional Breakpoint'

Answer (score 13):

With VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), you also have:

> ### [Breakpoints View: Conditions for exception breakpoints](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/c1e4683c6a35101bf09f22b6f02c5b2019ddb5eb/release-notes/v1_52.md#breakpoints-view-conditions-for-exception-breakpoints)

> We now support editing conditions for Exception breakpoints from the BREAKPOINTS view using the "`Edit Condition`" context menu action.
>
> For now, only the Mock Debug extension has a (fake) Exception Breakpoint condition support, but soon other debug extensions will follow - such as the Javascript debugger.
>
> [image: Edit Condition -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/edit-condition.png]
>
> [image: Exception Condition -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/exception-condition.png]

---

That applies to Node debugger in [VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/56b62268c9df79ae72305b364eb18f4f4b4cc9bb/release-notes/v1_53.md#debugging): see [issue 104453](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104453)

[image: conditional breakpoint]

> It is now possible to edit conditions for exception breakpoints and function breakpoints using the inline Edit Condition action or the new context menu actions.
>
> Using conditions it is possible for the user to specify that the program should break on an exception only when a particular condition is met.
>
> Currently the Javascript debug extension support conditions for exception or function breakpoints and soon other debug extensions will support it as well.
>
> [image: Breakpoint zone widget colored -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/56b62268c9df79ae72305b364eb18f4f4b4cc9bb/release-notes/images/1_53/breakpoints.gif]

---

VSCode 1.55 (March 2021) will add:

> ### [Inline menu to edit condition and hit count](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/091e2e1c75c96c796655023718ea39d98e5dc51d/release-notes/v1_55.md#improvements-to-breakpoints)

> We now show an inline menu for editing conditions and hit counts for function breakpoints.
> Previously the inline edit button would choose automatically what condition to edit, now the menu should make the flow easier and give more control to the user.
>
> [image: breakpoint condition menu]
>
> ### Access types of data breakpoints
>
> Data breakpoints now support more access types to break on:
>
> - **Break on Read**: breakpoint will be hit every time a variable gets read.
> - **Break on Access**: breakpoint will be hit every time a variable is accessed.
>
> As a reminder, data breakpoints can be added from a context menu in the VARIABLES view and we already supported Break on Value Change.
>
> For now, only the Mock Debug extension has (fake) Data Breakpoint support for all three access types, but soon other debug extensions will follow - such as the Java extension.
>
> [image: break on access types]

Answer (score 5):

if for some reason you cannot make conditional breakpoint to work follow below approach.
write if statements in your code and put breakpoint inside it.

```
if(condition): # condition when you want to program to stop
   print("pause execution here")  # put a breakpoint on this line.
```

Comment: Or you might store the condition into a temporary boolean variable and simply set the conditional breakpoint to monitor said boolean variable. Caveman-like debugging but it works/

Answer (score 0):

You can use c++ functions.
I used this to partially match a string in a variable for conditional breakpoint with an expression:
`variable.find("string")"`